# simple dice app - going in chronological order instead of random one (Xcode - Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, dice

what I need to change in this piece of code in Xcode(Swift) to make the dices go chronologically from 1 to 6 (every time I press the button +1)and over again instead of going randomly as it is now ?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change what you have to the following:
** Keep line with `let diceArray` as is! **

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView1: UIImageView!
  
  let diceArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; /* <- use what you have already
  
  @IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if(typeof(diceImageView1.image)=="undefined") diceImageView1.image=null;
    switch(diceImageView1.image) {
      case diceArray[0]: diceImageView1.image = diceArray[1]; break;
      case diceArray[1]: diceImageView1.image = diceArray[2]; break;
      case diceArray[2]: diceImageView1.image = diceArray[3]; break;
      case diceArray[3]: diceImageView1.image = diceArray[4]; break;
      case diceArray[4]: diceImageView1.image = diceArray[5]; break;
      default: diceImageView1.image = diceArray[0];
    }
  }
}
```

We are checking `if(typeof(diceImageView1.image)=="undefined")` because I don't know how the code works, so, just to be sure, we set `diceImageView1.image=null;`.
At first run, `diceImageView1.image` shouldn't be equal to any dice side, so `default` will set it to `[0]` which is the dice face with 1 on it.
Consecutive runs will `switch` to the next one: `[0]`(1) to `[1]`(2) through `[4]`(5) to `[5]`(6).
Once it's at `[5]`(6), there is no `case` for that, so `default`, as above, will set it to `[0]`(1).

Comment: I just realized that you didn't specify a language, I answered as if it was for JavaScript, You accepted my answer = I assume it worked, What language is it?!?

Comment: Actually I accepted the answer but I haven’t checked before now to be honest - I tried to import the code, but I get error message saying ,, cannot find "typeof" in scope" - and sorry I forgot to mention the language -  Swift in Xcode -  so it’s meant to be iOS app

Comment: Try without that line.

Comment: If no-go, then also without the `break;`s.